# C# Windows Forms - How to get previous SelectedItem in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get the previous Selected Item in a Combobox, the data is added in a list in the Form1_Load function.

```
  //Flavour Change Button
    private void CoboFlav_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItemPrice = (coboFlav.SelectedItem as Flavour).price;
        var selectedItemName = (coboFlav.SelectedItem as Flavour).name;

        var pre_item = pre_selIndex = (coboFlav.SelectedItem as Flavour).price;

        //var previousItem = flavourTea_Previous_Var = (coboFlav.SelectedItem as Flavour).price;

        //Item List
        Flavour listItem1 = ListCopy.MyList2.Find(x => (x.name == "- None -"));
        Flavour listItem2 = ListCopy.MyList2.Find(x => (x.name == "Lemon"));
        Flavour listItem3 = ListCopy.MyList2.Find(x => (x.name == "Passionfruit"));
        Flavour listItem4 = ListCopy.MyList2.Find(x => (x.name == "Yogurt"));

        //Checking Base Tea Box for adding price to currentItemTotal
        if (coboFlav.Text == listItem1.name || coboFlav.Text == listItem2.name || coboFlav.Text == listItem3.name || coboFlav.Text == listItem4.name)
        {
            //Increment Item Cost Value & take away previous item cost 
            currentTotalItemCost += selectedItemPrice - pre_item;
        }


        //Update CUrrentTotal Text
        CurrentTotal.Text = currentTotalItemCost.ToString();
    }
```

If the user selected an option in the combobox the selectedPrice int is increased. I am trying to take away the previousItemCost and im having trouble understanding how to find the previous selected user input.

I am not really sure how to approach this, I have seen a couple of other people declare a new int as -1 and set the SelectedIndex to that. But I don't really understand that solution. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Also I am quite new to windows forms as I came from a Unity background.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a *previously selected item* as far as the combobox is concerned. You'll need to keep track of what's been selected in a list yourself.

Comment: as @KenWhite said, the easiest way is to track the previous item every time the current selected item changes by having a ```previousSelection``` variable which keeps track of it. Or if you need a history, then a List would do the job.

Comment: While this is not a provided functionality, it's not too hard to implement; and If this is a functionality you need often, then you can just derive your own custom control from `ComboBox`, which will keep track of the previous selection and expose this data as a property.

Comment: You should create a separate `List<Flavour>` to add/remove the distinct items. Then the sums and counts will be easy. Like `CurrentTotal.Text = selList.Sum(x => x.price).ToString();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you want a special kind of ComboBox. In your "object oriented programming" course you learned that if you want a class similar to another class, but with some special behaviour, you should create a derived class:

```
class PreviousSelectedComboBox : ComboBox         // TODO: invent proper name
{
    private int previousSelectedIndex = -1;

    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    public virtual int PreviousSelectedIndex {get; private set;}
    {
        get => this.previousSelectedIndex;
        set => this.previousSelectedIndex = value;
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    public override int SelectedIndex
    {
        get => base.SelectedIndex;
        set
        {
            if (this.SelectedIndex != value)
            {
                this.PreviousSelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
                base.SelectedIndex = value;

                // TODO: call OnSelectedIndexChanged?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test** In a dummy test program or a unit test, check if [ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.onselectedindexchanged?view=net-5.0) is called by `base.SelectedIndex`, If not, call it in the `SelectedIndex.Set`.
Also check what happens if `ComboBox.SelectedItem.Set` is called. Does this change the selected index by calling your overridden property SelectedIndex?

**Event**: I don't think that you need an event PreviousSelectedIndexChanged. It won't add anything, because this event is raised whenever event SelectedIndexChanged is raised, so those who want to get notified when PreviousSelectedIndex changes, could subsbribe to event SelectedIndexChanged.

Still, if you want such an event, follow the pattern that is used in property SelectedIndex and in OnSelectedIndexChanged.